# Improve the "How do I ask a good question" article

Tags: feature-request, help-center

The current [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) has five main points:

- Research
- Be on-topic
- Be specific
- Relevance
- Be open-minded

The "Be Specific" isn't specific enough. Here is that section:

> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

Now to ask a vague question means that it is not clear and may bring up some broad answer. This means the question can be flagged as "Unclear what you're asking about" or "Too Broad". This encourages you to create more specific questions to avoid these flags but supposedly allow you to create broad, unclear questions.

Can this section be improved so it discourages vague questions instead of saying that vague questions are acceptable but will bring vague answers?

Comment: I like that this is also a meta issue (be specific isn't specific enough)

Comment: @Oded May be we should have a Meta Meta-Stack Exchange site like for all the other Stack Exchange sub sites. I'm probably not the 1st one having this idea ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The meta is not meta enough. We have to dig deeper!

Comment: @SimonKlaver Ask Gödel about that please :o) (may be M.C. Escher or J.S. Bach as well).