# How do I ask a good question without getting struck by the hammer of downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes, closed-questions, rules

I've been asking questions here for 8 months and every time I try to ask a question it either gets downvoted within 10 minutes and people say that "**you're just looking to gain reputation**" and "**come back with a proper question**" or "**it's a duplicate**" and "**do more research**". And it also gets closed with people, without even reading the question: "**It's off-topic**", "**homework question"**, "**too vague**",. It unsurprisingly gets downvoted to hell within hours, if not minutes, and me reliably asking why you downvoted, and me getting hit with the quotes above. And I'm not even going to discuss the 1-2 sentence questions that aren't even closed for being too vague, but somehow 4 whole hours of editing,2 hours of research and days of thinking is somehow too vague?! Anyway, I've been trying for the last 4 months to try and ask good, worthwhile questions, but I can't do that without getting pelted with the downvote arrows.  Can anyone help me with this?

I've looked at the help center and read it **thoroughly** multiple times, and searched up anything with "how to ask good questions" or "how to participate in meta and not die trying". I've tried to do that, but no matter what I'm always struck by downvotes, for I don't even know what reason. I'm just looking for a way to thrive and contribute to this community, and nobody's letting me do that. It might be that I'm just too late and too new.

And go figure, the question is closed because there's another one with an answer, that doesn't help me at all.

I don't even know if I'm going to post another question because it'll get 12 downvotes in an hour, no matter what the hell I do.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375424/why-is-wikipedia-asking-for-donations (deleted) This one was me thinking that they're closely related somehow.

[Proposed "Platinum Badges"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375417/proposed-platinum-badges)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Each site on the network has its own rules. You probably should ask this question on the child meta of the relevant site. That said, you need to make sure your question addresses specific points that are not already covered in the "How to Ask" Help Center article on that site.

Comment: Have you seen: [Improve the "How do I ask a good question" article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272144/282094)? Related: [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/282094), [this answer to "How do I write a good title?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/282094), [Jon Skeet's blog post "Writing the perfect question"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: The wiki's of tags often have guidance as well, with links to even more background: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info it is worth taking all of that into account before posting. Also [*Heavily consider not requesting a new feature if you're new*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying/44189#heavily-consider-not-requesting-a-new-feature-if-youre-new)

Comment: You might as well leave in the links to the questions. Nobody can vote on them while they are deleted and they are now referenced in the answer.

Comment: I wish I started like 10 years ago..,.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) Per that post, here on Meta, voting on feature requests is used to indicate whether people agree or disagree with a suggestion. A feature request that is perfectly on-topic for this site can get downvoted if people don't want to see it implemented on the sites.

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog  I already read that,so not at all

Comment: How about [Does piling up downvotes help this site in any useful way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322324/377214) The answer by Tinkeringbell addresses this question nicely.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about in my question. Sending me links that I've already talked about in my question!

Comment: I don't see where you talk about [Does piling up downvotes help this site in any useful way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322324/377214) in your question. As for the first link, my apologies; I didn't notice it because it wasn't linked, only text.

Comment: Maybe I should just focus on learning about this site even more,instead of raging on the keyboard.

Comment: @BruhMoments That would definitely be a good idea. Especially since "How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?" (which you claim to have read) specifically states "Don't criticize, put down, or insult. Be constructive" and "Don't whine or complain". Some of your comments both here and elsewhere don't seem to be following that advice.

Comment: Here is a [list of questions asked since June 2020 that have a score => 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Newest&q=created%3a2020-06-01...%20score%3a5...%20is%3aquestion). This might help you get a sense of what's considered a good question.

Comment: you'll also know that there's a lot of over 2000 rep users

Comment: In the question list? I actually did want to at least strip out the questions posted by staff since those are really just announcements but I didn't see a way to do that here in the [advanced options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). I don't think there's a way to search for questions based on the reputation of the person asking (and I think that's on purpose, IIRC *that's* been requested before) but I don't think it should matter much for learning what a good question looks like (unlike announcements, which are different).

Comment: Even on this site [99% of people have between 1 and 199 rep](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta/2009-06-28/188189#188189) The other 1% are, I admit a pretty active minority.

Comment: You can always ask in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) before posting a new question if you're worried and how it will be received

Comment: Clearly, you simply do not understand what the sites are for. Your example of your question about Wikipedia proves it. You think it is on topic here, but it is not. So yes, we do downvote bad, or in your case, off topic questions. And we do close them. That is how the sites of Stack Exchange are kept clean and organized.

Comment: The Wikipedia one was the only one I legit thought was bad,only after I got 8 downvotes. But the other ones I'm confused. 50k rep users can just shrug it off,obviously.

Answer (score 12):

This site is about what happens on Stack Exchange. Per the [help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) is the primary feedback and discussion space for issues that relate to the sites on the Stack Exchange Network and the software that powers this platform.

[Why is wikipedia asking for donations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375424/why-is-wikipedia-asking-for-donations) is about Wikipedia, not about Stack Exchange at all so it's not something you can ask about here. The closure message told you that.

[Platinum badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375417/proposed-platinum-badges), however are on topic. The problem with that question is that it's already been suggested.

- So you're lacking research because you've not looked into whether it's been suggested before, or if you did you didn't say why your question provides a new slant on the topic or why users that have been here a long time need to be further motivated by extra badges
- and [this being Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) it's quite possible people simply think that platinum badges aren't a good idea and voted accordingly.

So make sure your questions are about Stack Exchange and try to see if something similar has been asked before and what reception it received when it was asked. If you are going to repeat what's been asked before then you need to offer some new insight into the problem.

Finally start from thinking about why something is a problem and then how to solve it rather than thinking of a feature (e.g. platinum badges) and then wondering how to justify wanting it.

Comment: Well all it said for platinum badges was just are they going to bring them? I actually thought of some